# WP_Query not getting all posts, just tagged posts

Tags: theme-development, wp-query, loop

I'm trying to create an archive page that grabs every post submitted. At the moment, I have this, which doesn't work:

```
<?php

   $args = array ();
   $query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
  while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $query->the_post();?>

        <div class="post">


<?php first_item() ?>



<?php
  }
} else {
  // no posts found
}

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

However, if I  change the array to:

```
   $args = array (
  'tag'                 => 'films',
);
```

It starts receiving all posts tagged as films.

How come this is only working with tagged posts, and not for **every** post?

I do have a loop on the front page and on custom page, so could they be conflicting?

Comment: Your code is not complete, I guess. Where do you close `div.post`? What does `first_item()` do exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You've given `WP_Query` and empty argument set, effectively asking it to get "nothing". Try:

```
$args = array ();
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
var_dump($query);
```

As soon as you give it something to latch onto, like your tag argument, the query works. To get all of your posts pass a `post_type` argument.

```
$args = array ('post_type'=>'post');
$query = new wp_query( $args );
var_dump($query);
```

Or to get all post types...

```
$args = array ('post_type'=>'any');
$query = new wp_query( $args );
var_dump($query);
```

Or to only get particular post types...

```
$args = array ('post_type'=> array('post','book'));
$query = new wp_query( $args );
var_dump($query);
```